# cPanel ~ DNS issues with www, in CNAME

Tags: dns, cpanel, cname

Ok long story short, we have had to upgrade our hosting faster than i can contact old clients to get the domain registrar information to change the nameservers. so this is what we have...

Our old shared cpanel hosting has about 8 Add-On domains that need to be pointed to our new server, so for each Add-On domain that needs to be pointed away, i have deleted all the zone records for the domains except for the A record which points to the IP of the new server.

I then picked up these domains as an Add-On domains in the new server and of course the default zone configuration gives each domain a CNAME for:

www 14400 IN CNAME mydomain.com.

Problem is that this is not working at all.

Did I miss something?

For clarification mydomain.com accessed directly, its the www. that is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the . after www as that ends the DNS record at being www. removing the trailing dot will auto-append the domain name to the www. query

If this is not the issue than it is due to DNS propagation and you just need to wait it out.

Comment: yea that was a typo, the do not have the . after www

Comment: if a dig mydomain.com returns the correct IP than it is just a matter of time see: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/propagation-times

Comment: www.domain.org. 14400 IN CNAME domain.org

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just DNS propagation problem. Try to change TTL to 3600.